# Regex to match data from a webpage

Tags: regex, vb.net, webbrowser-control

This is probably a simple question for someone experienced with regex, but I'm having a little trouble. I'm looking to match lines of data like this shown below:

> SomeAlpha Text CrLf CrLf 15 CrLf CrLf 123 132 143 CrLf CrLf 12313 CrLf CrLf 12/123

Where the `"SomeAlpha Text"` is just some text with space and potentially punctuation. The first number is something between 1 and 30,000. The second set of numbers (123 132 143) are between 1 and 500,000 (each number). The next number is somewhere between 1 and 500,000. The final set is (1–30,000)/(1–30,000). This is the code I've put together so far:

```
Dim Pattern As String = "[.*]{1,100}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,4}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6]" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,6}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,5}/[0-9]{1,5}"

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(match.ToString & Chr(13) & Chr(13))

Next
```

And I'm currently getting 0 matches, even though I know there should be at least 1 match. Any advice on where my pattern is wrong would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm a line break that definitely matches. It wouldn't surprise me if that vbCrLf doesn't work. Try \r\n

Comment: You might be able to do a replace on the offending chars before applying the regex and then not have to worry about them at all.

Comment: @OGHaza In VB.NET, `vbCrLf` is a constant that is equal to `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"[.*]{1,100}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,4}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6]" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,6}" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "[0-9]{1,5}/[0-9]{1,5}"
```

has quite a few problems:

- The `*` in `"[.*]{1,100}"` tells the previous character to repeat as many times as possible, and is therefore unnecessary. Replace it with `".{1,100}"` or `".*"`
- You say the first number is between 0 and 30000. `"[0-9]{1,4}"` only allows for 4 digits (0 to 9999). Replace it with `"[0-9]{1,5}"`, which allows for any number between 0 and 99999.
- You accidentally put `]` instead of `}` at three places in this part: `"[0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6] [0-9]{1,6]"`. Replace it with `"[0-9]{1,6} [0-9]{1,6} [0-9]{1,6}"`

Try doing what I said above. It should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually fixed this myself by doing almost exactly what you have said!